# Add Body to IMethod

Tags: eclipse, plugins, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing an Eclipse Plugin to do some simple code generation. I'm able to grab an IMethod representing the Method I need to modify, but I'm unsure how to actually write additional code in its body.  I know this can be done with AST nodes, so is there a way to convert betwen IMethod and MethodDeclaration or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMethod is a class of JDT's Java model while MethodDeclaration is a node class of the JDT AST. The Java model has no connection to the AST. But you can use the model to create an AST, typically ICompilationUnit (represents a Java source file) is used, although creating an AST from a string is also possible.

I would suggest checking out [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html)

---

Edit:

Possibly "no *direct* connection" would have been the better wording. In the [JDT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#From_an_IJavaElement_to_its_declaring_ASTNode) is the following:

> **How to go from one of IBinding, IJavaElement, ASTNode to another?**
>
> [...]
>
> **From an IJavaElement to an IBinding**
>
> If you only need the binding key and not the binding object itself, look for a 'getKey()' method in a subtype of IJavaElement. This method returns the binding key, which can be useful in many situations e.g. see next point. Note that not all subtypes of IJavaElement have a corresponding binding, e.g. IType and IMethod have one but IPackageFragment and IImportContainer do not.
>
> If you really need the binding objects you can use 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createBindings(IJavaElement[], IProgressMonitor)'. Note that this operation is slightly expensive, compared to just getting the binding key, as the bindings have to be created.
>
> **From an IJavaElement to its declaring ASTNode**
>
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.findDeclaringNode(String) - The string parameter is the binding key, see previous point.

Comment: Good article, thank you.   It was quite easy to search for a method in the java model, so I grabbed an IMethod.  I then parsed the ICompilationUnit into an AST, grabbed the mehod declarations from that, and compared their java element (MethodDeclaration.resolvebinding().getJavaElement()) to the original IMethod.  When they matched, I knew that MethodDeclaration(AST) corresponded to the original IMethod(JavaModel).  I'm sure this isn't the proper way to do this, but it worked.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added an excerpt from the JDT FAQ where the method CompilationUnit.findDeclaringNode() is mentioned. Possibly that can simplify your code.